# How to Map.addLayer() rainfall featureCollection over globe using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, large-datasets, precipitation, feature-collection

I am trying to print the precipitation imageCollection allover the whole world but I allways get only a part of the image.
as you see in the image, the north of europe is empty and event when I use the inspector, there is no values there.
not that the CHIRPS dataset that I am using is a global dataset.

[image]

```
  var startYear = '2000';
  var endYear = '2013';
  var dataset_precip= CHIRPS.filterDate(startYear, endYear);
  Map.addLayer(dataset_precip,{},'dataset_precip');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not a GEE error/lack of data. This dataset hasn't global coverage. From [CHIRPS: Rainfall Estimates from Rain Gauge and Satellite Observations](https://www.chc.ucsb.edu/data/chirps)

> **CHIRPS Overview**
>
> Climate Hazards Group InfraRed Precipitation with Station data
> (CHIRPS) is a 35+ year quasi-global rainfall data set. Spanning
> **50°S-50°N** (and all longitudes) and ranging from 1981 to near-present, CHIRPS incorporates our in-house climatology, CHPclim,
> 0.05° resolution satellite imagery, and in-situ station data to create gridded rainfall time series for trend analysis and seasonal drought
> monitoring.

Comment: thank you. is there a dataset with a global coverage or is there a way to combine or merge diffrent datasets and imageCollection?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about a precipitation product with global coverage. You can try [PERSIANN](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/NOAA_PERSIANN-CDR), but it has 60ºS-60ºN coverage